# Let $f: N × N \to R$ be the function given by $f(a,b)=\frac{a+2}{3b}$ What is the image of f? Justify your answer.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I know how I would go about justifying this, and how to get the image of a function with just x, but I'm not exactly sure how to get it on questions like this with an x and y coordinate. Any help would be appreciated.

> Let $f: N × N\to R$ be the function given by $f(a,b)=\frac{a+2}{3b}$ What is the image of f? Justify your answer.

Comment: Is $N$ supposed to be the set of natural numbers (either positive integers or non-negative integers, depending on your choice of definitions)?  If so, consider that the image will be a subset of $\mathbf Q$, the set of rational numbers.  You can describe this subset by considering the possible values of the numerator and the denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range is $\{\frac {n+2}{3m}: n,m\in \mathbb N\} $.